# It is possible to change Page default in FastReport?

Tags: delphi, default, fastreport

I have a little problem.

I've build a report with 2 pages:

- **Page1** shows a general items with sum.
- **Page2** shows a detailed of each item.

In the form I choose which kind of page I want to see.

If I want general information I choose option 1 and I saw the "Page1".

But, if I want to see detailed information I saw "Page1" along with "Page2", instead of the "page2" content only.

I tried to set `page1.visible := False` but If I do that I saw nothing, but If I set `page2.visible := False` and choose option1 then I saw the content.

Why can't I have the same result ?

It seems to me that the "Page1" is set as the default page and I can't have this page not visible.

So I'm searching to change that. If it is possible, where can I alter that ?

Thanks.

Comment: How about PrintPreparedReport('2', 1, False, frAll); ?

Comment: Can you please precise your Delphi and FastReport versions?

Answer (score 0):

you must sure if **Page2** has **MasterData band**.
where Fast Report Page not Appear until it has **MasterData**.
Where **Master Data band** Represent **Main engine**.
and Then your Code will be run **`page1.visible := False`**.